# Can't load chrome profile with selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

im tryng to load my default chrome profile but instead of opening  my profile it open a new istance of chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver



#object of ChromeOptions class
o = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#adding Chrome Profile Path
o.add_argument = {'user-data-dir':r'C:\Users\liamm\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default'}
#set chromedriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\liamm\Desktop\selenium\driver\chromedriver.exe", options=o)
#maximize browser
driver.maximize_window()
#launch URL
driver.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm")
```